# Paypal Sandbox How to Check Billing Plans and Billing Agreements

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I've been building a subscription based on the REST API Billing plans and agreements using these sample codes from [PayPal-PHP-SDK](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#billing). However I can't seem to find the created billing plans and the billing agreements from my testings in sandbox and developer Paypal sites. Is there a way to check if the process was a success?

Here are my steps:

1. Create billing plan
2. Activate billing plan
3. Create Agreement based on active billing plan
4. Execute Agreement [Response was an Agreement Object with state = 'Active']

Answer (score 3):

I have been facing the same problem but found a solution which helped me on the issue.

Goto Sandbox paypal

1)https://www.sandbox.paypal.com

2)Click on login and login with your business sandbox account you can create sandbox account in https://developer.paypal.com

3)in now dashboard after login you will see My account tools
under My account tools click on
My Business Setup

4)it will take you to this page Welcome to your PayPal Business Account
on this page click on profile link right next of logout button.

5)Now you will see a new paypal header menu

it will have a link tools in the header menu

hover on tools and click on All Tools 
then click on Recurring Payments

here you can see all the data for Recurring Payments

i have also found paypal guide for this to 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/recurring-payments-dashboard/#open-the-recurring-payments-dashboard

Comment: This page only shows the subscribed customers (i.e. the billing agreements) - but not the billing plans themselves. There is no way to interact with your billing plans through the PayPal websites. And the "website" is a strange mix/mess of pages with old and new design - obviously an incomplete transition to a new infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GET billing plans operation.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans?page_size=3&status=ACTIVE&page_size=2&page=1&total_required=yes \
```

-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"

Read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#plan_list)

Comment: thank you! But, the billing plans and agreements are not reflecting on the sandbox site. Specifically, I wanted to check :
- which billing plans has agreements
- view individual agreements info

Comment: This is a rather old issue (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/5) which is still not solved. You have to store agreement IDs in your own DB by the script on the callback URL when the user subscribes for your service.